# Java Arraylist and Map

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

I don't have idea how to search this:

```
Random generator = new Random();
Map<Integer, ArrayList> mapOfprevOp = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<Integer> listPrev = new ArrayList<>();


listPrev = mapOfprevOp.get(operacja);
System.out.println(listPrev); // it will show []

int rnd = generator.nextInt(op_cnt) + 1;
listPrev.add(rnd);
System.out.println(mapOfprevOp.get(operacja)); // it will show value of listPrev
```

Why second System.out print me on the screen value of listPrev?

It shouldn't still print [] ?

```
listPrev = mapOfprevOp.get(operacja);
```

This line works different than i could expect?

Comment: The map will show the values you added to the list because it is the same object.

Comment: So how to assign value of Map to ArrayList?

Comment: How could I separate it?

Answer (score 0):

This would suggest that at your first `System.out.println` invocation the list is empty.

If you look here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29.  We can see that the toString method for a list returns the elements between square brackets.  Thus [] is an empty list.

At the second call you have added an element which is why you see it.  You need to bare in mind that in Java we pass objects by reference meaning that your `listPrev` references the SAME LIST as the one contained in the map.

If you want to just get the value, then I would suggest you change

```
listPrev = mapOfprevOp.get(operacja);
```

to be

```
listPrev.addAll(mapOfprevOp.get(operacja));
```

This will add all of the elements from `mapOfprevOp.get(operacja)` to listPrev without subsequent operations affecting the map which seems to be what you want.

Also, `Map<Integer, ArrayList> mapOfprevOp = new HashMap<>();`  Generally it is  better to use interface types in delcarations like you have with Map.  So I would consider switching `ArrayList` to be `List`.

The object that you use its self can still be an ArrayList, like this:

Map mapOfprevOp = new HashMap<>();
List listPrev = new ArrayList<>();

This means that if you wanted to change it to be a LinkedList, you would only change it in one place rather than 3.  Note that with the exception of Arrays.asList lists all lists can be resized.

Comment: It must be ArrayList, becouse I will put there more elements. Here is only snippet of code

Comment: Edited the answer to explain more - since I think you misunderstand that point a little.

Comment: I just need to get value of mapOfprevOp.get(operacja) not assign listPrev to it.

Comment: Added abit more to explain.  But basically look at using addAll() or making a copy of the list.